# Use replica member as standalone server? MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup a mongodb replica member for read-only (Reporting), since we need to connect tableu with it, we are using mongosql to transform those queries, however all the queries are still going to the primary server and sometimes it is overloading the DB due to some missing indices.
Is this even possible?

I have configured this replica member to be hidden, cannot vote and with priority 0. Also, I have set the following mongo uri in mongosql: mongodb://localhost:27017/ and omitted the replicaSet connection options as per the mongod docs:
When connecting to a replica set it is important to give a seed list of at least two mongod instances. If you only provide the connection point of a single mongod instance, and omit the replicaSet, the client will create a standalone connection. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/connection-string/

I am expecting to have one replica member isolated just for reporting purposes. We currently have a cluster with 4 members, and we would like to keep just one for reporting for tableu with mongosql

Answer (score 0):

The result of [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/) command will give more information to answer your question.

But I will try to answer your question based on the available data.

Based on your question, it looks like all your 4 nodes of the clusters are running in the same localhost machine and the primary node is running in port 27017. So check the [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/) value and find out on which port the hidden node is running and try to connect to that port instead of 27017.

Comment: Not actually, all mongod instances are running in separate machines within the same DC. so there are 1 mongod instance per machine under 27017.

The problem is: Whenever I specify in the URI a replica member to connect to, this replica member redirects all the traffic to the primary one

Comment: I replicated the same scenario, it works perfectly for me. check the rs.status() value and find out the correct hostname and port number of the secondary node and use it in the connection string.